# Requesting tag synonyms

Tags: discussion

**Note: I could not already find a question on Meta answering this. If there is one, then please provide a link.**

I've been looking through the tags recently, and have seen a few that I think deserve to be synonyms. Of course, I don't have enough rep to suggest synonyms myself, but some tags (e.g. [uvw-mapping](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uvw-mapping)) are just slightly differently worded tags of others ([uv-mapping](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uv-mapping)) and occur just as much. The reason this is really annoying me is because tag wikis written for one are then not used for the other, and IMO this removes the entire point. Is there any way to request a tag synonym?

Comment: http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/155/the-these-tags-are-useless-thread

Comment: Slick and Slick2D should be synonyms too. But it apparently requires a mod. Something about version synonyms.

Comment: @Byte56 If you have 5 up votes in either tag, you can _suggest_ the other as a synonym and then it can be voted on.

Comment: Well, I'm the top user in both [slick](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/tags/slick/topusers) and [slick2d](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/tags/slick2d/topusers). I still can't suggest a synonym. Because "Version specific synonyms can only be created by moderators"

Comment: @Byte56 What exactly is a 'Version specific synonym'?

Comment: Good question. I assume it thinks that Slick and Slick2d are different versions of the same library.