# Tag synonyms and "version specific" synonyms

Tags: discussion, support, tags

Like user Polar [asked 8 years ago](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1104/requesting-tag-synonyms), I too tried to propose a tag synonym for [game-maker](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-maker) since I meet both the rep and the question score requirements. However, I get the error:

> Failed to propose synonym:
> Version specific synonyms can only be created by moderators

I want to suggest [game-maker-studio-2](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-maker-studio-2) (11 questions) as a synonym of the main tag [game-maker](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-maker) (420 questions). Reason is, GMS2 is just a new version of the engine, but that seems no different from merging [unity5](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unity5) questions in the main tag [unity](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unity), or [xna-4.0](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xna-4.0) into [xna](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xna).

I think this is different from [having separate tags](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2754/should-we-have-separate-game-maker-and-game-maker-studio-tags-for-legacy-users) for [game-maker](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-maker) and [game-maker-studio](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-maker-studio), because GMS1 and GMS2 are quite similar, and their differences involve only the actual engine implementation. On the other hand, pre-Studio versions (up to 8.1, I guess) are basically deprecated and no longer supported, thus we can expect nobody is going to ask a question about old, specific versions.

To sum up: GMS and GMS2 are different versions of the same software and basically expose the same functionalities. Since earlier versions are obsolete, we could merge everything into the [game-maker](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-maker) main tag.

Comment: I don't mind doing something like this; I'm not familiar with this software so I'll wait until this post gets a couple upvotes before I do.

Comment: For folks who are familiar with this software: I'd appreciate if you could post an answer arguing why / why not merge these tags (or upvoting an answer you agree with). [See this answer relating to Unity vs Unity 5 as an example](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2236/39518). The extra information can help us ensure we're making a sound call here.

Comment: should game-maker-dnd also be a synonym?

Comment: @Evorlor I think nobody has ever used such tag, so there's no need to take it into account for the moment

Comment: Some will still ask questions on the old thing. We still get XNA questions. That's out of rotation since what, 2013?

Answer (score 2):

I have proposed [game-maker-studio-2](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-maker-studio-2) as a synonym for [game-maker](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-maker).

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/tags/game-maker/synonyms

(I also accidentally proposed [game-maker-studio](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-maker-studio) as a synonym. ‍♂️)

Comment: We can accidentally downvote twice that tag and your blunder will be no more :P